# Does AWS AppSync with custom database support subscriptions?

Tags: ios, mysql, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-appsync

I am using appsync with custom database (MYSQL). I want to know if it will support subscriptions ? I know subscriptions work with DynamoDB, but will they work for custom database ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subscriptions in AWS AppSync are invoked as a response to a mutation. This means that you can make any data source in AWS AppSync real time by specifying a GraphQL schema directive on a mutation. You can read more information about it [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/real-time-data.html)